# Fixed-size array issue

Tags: arrays, bytes32

Maybe this question it seems to be stupid but is it possible to change elements of fixed-size array like bytes32. For example:

bytes32 _b32 = sha3(1);
_b32[0] = 100;                // => Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to mutate elements of a fixed-sized array, but not a fixed-sized **byte array** (like `bytes32`).

So this is valid:

```
byte[32] myBytes;
myBytes[3] = 0x5;
```

but this is *not* valid:

```
bytes32 myBytes;
myBytes[3] = 0x5;  // TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
```